# How to store firebase instance id token?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is firebase token is use to sent to specific device?

How do I store firebase token in MySQL?

From google website, It does not mention about the length of the token.

It seems to be very long.

Comment: Are you asking how to insert a text value into a mysql table?

Comment: Should I use text column type?

Comment: Are you answering my question with a question?

Comment: You ask me a question, I answer your question with a maybe answer in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Instance ID Token identifies a specific app on a specific device. From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials):

> Registration token - An ID generated by the FCM SDK for each client app instance.

The Instance ID Token indeed only expires in very few conditions. Also from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#access-the-registration-token):

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

The token is a relatively long string. Since you're unlikely to frequently search for it, I'd store in in a text field in your database.

Comment: regarding the bullet point "The app deletes Instance ID", when does it occur?

Comment: When you call `deleteInstanceId()` or `deleteToken()` on `FirebaseInstanceId` is my guess: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId